# Jira API | Error: "Operation value must be a string" - trying to set value nested two levels deep

Tags: json, ruby, hash, nested, jira-rest-api

Trying to create a new jira ticket of specific `requestType`, but it is nested two levels deep. Tried few possible alterations, but no luck. Here's the code I have,

```
require 'jira-ruby' # https://github.com/sumoheavy/jira-ruby

options = {
            :username => jira_username,
            :password => jira_password,
            :site     => 'https://jiraurl/rest/api/2/',
            :context_path => '',
            :auth_type => :basic,
            :read_timeout => 120
          }

client = JIRA::Client.new(options)
issue = client.Issue.build
fields_options = { 
  "fields" => 
  {
    "summary"   => "Test ticket creation",
    "description" => "Ticket created from Ruby",
    "project"   => {"key" => "AwesomeProject"},
    "issuetype" => {"name" => "Task"},
    "priority" => {"name" => "P1"},
    "customfield_23070" => 
    {
      "requestType" => {
        "name" => "Awesome Request Type"
      }
    }
  }
}
issue.save(fields_options)
```

`"errors"=>{"customfield_23070"=>"Operation value must be a string"}`

Also tried passing a `JSON` object to `customfield_23070`,
`"customfield_23070": { "requestType": { "name": "Awesome Request Type" } }`
still no luck, get the same error message.

If it helps, this is how `customfield_23070` looks like in our Jira, 
[image]

Does anyone know how to set `requestType` in this case, please? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 10):

It seems that for custom fields with specific data types (string/number), you must pass the value as:

```
"customfield_1111": 1
```

or:

```
"customfield_1111": "string"
```

instead of:

```
"customfield_1111":{ "value": 1 }
```

or:

```
"customfield_1111":{ "value": "string" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try this possible examples:

eg.1:

```
"customfield_23070"=>{"name"=>"requestType","value"=>"Awesome Request Type"}
```

eg.2:

```
"customfield_23070"=>{"requestType"=>"Awesome Request Type"}
```

eg.3:

```
"customfield_23070"=>{"value"=>"Awesome Request Type"}
```

eg.4

```
"customfield_23070"=>{"name"=>"Awesome Request Type"}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply! I have tried all these variations, unfortunately, they throw the same error message as well.

Answer (score 0):

for ref there are 2 methods depending upon the fields you are interacting with

have a look here '
[updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis-6848604](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/updating-an-issue-via-the-jira-rest-apis-6848604/)
' for the applicable fields for update via verb operations, the other fields you can use examples as per above, 
you can use both methods within the same call

```
{
 "update": {"description": [{"set": "Description by API Update - lets do this thing"}]},
 "fields": {"customfield_23310": "TESTING0909"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found how to do it.

You need to provide a string, and that string is the GUID of the RequestType.

In order to get that GUID. You need to run the following in a scriptrunner console:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def issue = ComponentAccessor.issueManager.getIssueByCurrentKey("ISSUE-400546") //Issue with the desired Request Type
def cf = ComponentAccessor.customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjectByName("Tipo de solicitud del cliente") //Change it to the name of your request type field
issue.getCustomFieldValue(cf)
```

Source: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/how-to-set-request-type-value-in-while-create-jira-issue/qaq-p/1106696